# Creating a 'git log' alias with formatting

Tags: git, terminal, alias, bash

I have a bunch of git aliases already set up in my .bash_profile that work correctly:

```
alias gst="git status"
alias gl="git pull"
alias gp="git push"
alias gd="git diff | mate"
alias gc="git commit -v"
alias gca="git commit -v -a"
alias gb="git branch"
alias gba="git branch -a"
```

I'm trying to add an alias for the following command, but keep running into an error:

```
git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)' --since='7 days ago'
```

What I'd like to do, is be able to type:

```
glog 'some amount of time'
```

So, being new at both aliases and git, I figured this would work:

```
alias glog="git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)' --since="
```

It throws the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '7 days ago': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

How can I correct my alias to make this work?

Thanks!

**[EDIT]**

I can make it work if I change the alias to:

```
alias glog="git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)'"
```

and then just type in:

```
glog --since='some amount of time'
```

but I'd really like to just type the amount of time, if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead, you can create a function in `.bash_profile`. It will allow you to use variables:

```
glog ()
{
        git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)' --since="$1"
}
```

And call it like usual:

```
glog "7 days ago"
```

---

> quick follow-up: how would I change the function to allow the
>   possibility of also appending the --author="so-and-so" flag? as in, I
>   could type glog "7 days ago" or blog "7 days ago" --author="bob"

I would do as like follows:

```
glog ()
{
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
       git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)' --since="$1"
    else
       git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)' --since="$1" --author="$2"
    fi
}
```

So you can call it with

```
glog "7 days ago"
glog "7 days ago" "bob"
```

Note that the `if [ -z "$2" ]; then` condition is checking if the second parameter is empty.  If so, just executes the code without `author`. Otherwise, it uses it.

Comment: This is awesome...I love the bonus that I don't have to type the '' after the command. Thanks!

@konsolebox - Seems to work for me with '' instead of "". Is there any behind the scenes stuff I should know about that '' makes screwy? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @konsolebox. It is strange but it worked to me with both `"$1"` and `'$1'`.

Comment: @fedorqui - I will, and thanks again! It's making me wait another minute before accepting.

Comment: @fedorqui - quick follow-up: how would I change the function to allow the possibility of also appending the --author="so-and-so" flag? as in, I could type glog "7 days ago" or blog "7 days ago" --author="bob"?

Comment: @fedorqui perfect, thanks so much! (Digging the [if -z "$2"] trick.)