# git alias with formatting in .gitconfig

Tags: git, git-alias

I've tried to do almost the same as described here, with same problems:

[Creating a 'git log' alias with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875287/creating-a-git-log-alias-with-formatting)

Solutions from this topic, of course, works.

But let say I want to group my git functions in git namespace, that is, to run `git gl "some time ago"`. 
But when I try to define function directly in .gitconfig:

`gl = "!f() { git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)' --since="$1"; }; f"`,

I have same error as before - `fatal: ambiguous argument ...lalala...`.

Same happens even when function is defined in .bash_profile and called from git alias.

It's not so big problem to use "global" functions, but I want to know, why this happens? And is it possible at all to define such function in .gitconfig?

Answer (score 3):

It's a quoting issue.

I have not seen anything that properly describes how quoting works in git aliases, but this works:

```
gl = "!f() { git log --all --pretty=format:'%h %cd %s (%an)' --since=\"$1\"; }; f"
```

That is, use backslash-double-quote to get the double quotes to go through to the shell alias, so that $1 is expanded.

Note that you must invoke it as:

```
$ git gl "one year ago"
```

If, instead of `$1`, you use `$*`, you can invoke it as:

```
$ git gl one year ago
```

which is kind of convenient.

Comment: +1. I am wondering how did you figure that out? trial and error?

Comment: Experimentation.  Helpful items include setting GIT_TRACE (to nonzero) in the environment, and setting -x in the shell function, so you can see what shows up where.  (I did the experimentation a while ago, and left some commented out aliases in my .gitconfig as a reminder to myself.)